# Force element to scroll instead of going off screen Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want my web chat app to stay at the screen size, and instead of the whole page scrolling.

My App Should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4Vwd.png)

**But** when the messages list overflows, it does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDUNo.png)

The messages and users lists should scroll inside themselves instead of forcing the entire page to scroll.

A simplified version of my app is here
https://play.tailwindcss.com/893jmRzvG4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `h-full` to `h-[80vh]`

[See here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JaZb5TKgeq)